# No images on a web page when using rewriterule

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(iphone)/(.*)\.html$ /$2.php?specialversion=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My problem is that when viewing http://www.example.com/iphone/mypage2.html, mypage2.php gets called and output contents but none of the images or even the CSS are working. How can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you call an image URL?

Comment: @Pekka. You got it! I should have tried that before. I realize that the addresses were relative to the HTML document (which is faked as being in the iphone folder). I got a customized 404 error message.
@all THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a new HEAD tag in your HTML in `mypage2.php` (and the other pages), when GET `specialversion` is set. The images will otherwise be fetched from http://www.example.com/iphone/images/... or similar, which is not redirected):

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

Of course, you could use another `RewriteRule` in the .htaccess instead.

```
RewriteRule ^(iphone/(?:images|style))/(.*)$ /$2.php?specialversion=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This RewriteRule rewrites `images` and `style` dirs. Remember that the cache wouldn't be used if a client uses both the main site and the `iphone` site (which probably isn't a problem).